# passing an event to a child component in React

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I'm new to React and this is a very noob question,  but I don't understand why this is not working.

I'm trying to build a simple todo List.

My `TodoList.js` Component looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

    export default class TodoList extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          todos:[
            {
              title:"todo1"
            },
            {
              title:"todo3"
            },
            {
              title:"todo2"
            }
          ]
        }

      }

      handleRemove(idx){
        alert('works');
      }

      render(){
        var todos = this.state.todos.map(function(t,idx){
          return(<TodoItem
                    remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this,idx)}
                    title={t.title}
          />)
        })

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>To do</h1>
          <div>{todos}</div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

My child Component looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

    export default class TodoItem extends Component{
      render(){
        return (
          <div>{this.props.title}
            <button onClick={this.props.remove}>X</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

But I get a TypeError with "Cannot read property 'handleRemove' of undefined". I'm wondering why inside the map function `{this}` is undefined?

I tried to put this `this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this)` into the constructor.

Didn't change anything. Shouldn't `this` also be defined inside the `.map()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `this` as the [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be used as
>   callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as
>   its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is
>   determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen
>   by a function.

on `map`:

```
render(){
        var todos = this.state.todos.map(function(t,idx){
          return(<TodoItem
                    remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this,idx)}
                    title={t.title}
          />)
        }, this)

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>To do</h1>
          <div>{todos}</div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to automatically preserve the current `this` context:

```
var todos = this.state.todos.map((t,idx) => {
  return(<TodoItem
    remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this,idx)}
    title={t.title}
  />)
})
```

Comment: ahhhhhhh, thanks! how could i have been so blind ! Thanks !